# Can I update log4j 1.2 xml configuration file programmatically?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I know it is possible to reload log4j's xml configuration while the application is running, but the searching I've done only shows how to do this when the XML config file is edited manually via a text editor.

I want to be able to dynamically change the level of the root logger in my application via a web page and persist that change to the log4j XML configuration, so I won't have to change the log level again if I restart the application. Is it possible to do this, or can the log4j XML file only be updated manually?

I am using log4j 1.2 in my application.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Its a text file, just update it.

Answer (score 1):

for any chump who finds themselves stuck dealing with this, it is possible to write out the data as properties using

```
org.apache.log4j.config.PropertyPrinter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this by [PropertyConfigurator configure and watch](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#configureAndWatch%28java.lang.String,%20long%29).

> Read the configuration file configFilename if it exists. Moreover, a thread will be created that will periodically check if configFilename has been created or modified. The period is determined by the delay argument. If a change or file creation is detected, then configFilename is read to configure log4j.